# camera preview gives gray images

Tags: java, android, opencv

i am developing android app using android sdk camera. on camera preview i need the frame content so i am using PreviewCallback to return the data in byte array, now my problem is saving the data in mat object the mat return gray images:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Mat src = new Mat(previewSize.height, previewSize.width, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(255));
    src.put(0, 0, data);
    Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/1.jpg", src);
}
```

anybody can help me to generate argb images

note: i am using NV21 in preview image format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
Mat src = new Mat(previewSize.height, previewSize.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

If it does not work, it means your `data` is already gray, so you must have set it as gray somewhere in your code.